# How to execute a code depending on if conditon in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, smarty, document-ready

I'm using smarty template.
Following is my Html code snippet

```
<input type="hidden" value="{$is_user_loggedin}" id="user_login_status">
```

I want to execute a piece of jQuery code depending on the value present in id "user_login_status". If it's blank only then execute the following code(i.e.`$(document).ready(function()`):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   if ('user_login_status' != ''){ alert("Nice");
        $(document).ready(function() {
        print_country("user_country", '', '');  
          });
    }
</script>
```

But it'snot working. I've added sample alert for testing purpose only. The code is executing even if the hidden field has no value. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: if ('user_login_status' != '') is always true

Comment: You are checkin the string with ' ' ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple if/else using `$('#user_login_status').val()` to get the value to test. Note how I have put the test inside the document ready function, because if you don't do that then you might run into problems with the hidden not existing at the time of trying to access it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('#user_login_status').val() != ''){
        // has a value - do somehting
    } else {
        // blank value
        print_country("user_country", '', ''); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

i don't think it's a smarty/jquery error but a coding error:

```
if ('user_login_status' != '')
```

will be always evaluated as true since you are comparing 2 string.

i think you should change it in

```
if ($('#user_login_status').val() != '')
```

Comment: Which you'd need to contain within $(document).ready() as well.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if ('user_login_status' != ''){ alert("Nice");
```

With:

```
if (document.getElementById('user_login_status').value != ''){ alert("Nice");
```

But you should ensure that `user_login_status` element is placed before the script block.